# Java Script not working. Using php based MVC

Tags: .htaccess

I have a small problem.
In my website I have two htaccess files.

htaccess (this is in root directory)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^$    public/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) public/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

This is in public directory where I have "graphics" directory.
htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

My directory structure is something like this:

```
root/public/js/abc.js 
root/application/controller/abccontroller.php  
root/application/model/abc.php  
root/application/abc.view
```

Java Script is not working

Comment: If you have firebug, check the image path with it and see if image is shown or you get the error: failed to load.

Comment: I an getting this response:
Request URL:http://www.example.com/home/content/**/*******/html/public/graphics/default_home.gif
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
\Safari/537.1
Response Headersview source
Accept-Ranges:none
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:366
Content-Type:text/html

Comment: Response is ok with status code 200

Only problem is content-type of response is
Content-Type:text/html 

That is the only problem

Answer (score 0):

> Response is ok with status code 200 Only problem is content-type of response is Content-Type:text/html That is the only problem

It sounds like either your php script is not setting the content type correctly (if these gifs/javascript is being routed through your scripts). Or, for some reason, your mime types aren't setup correctly. You can try adding a few [`AddType` directives](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype) in your htaccess:

```
AddType image/gif .gif
AddType image/jpeg .jpeg .jpg .jpe
AddType image/png .png
AddType text/plain .js
```

Comment: please check here  
http://www.atriviss.com/  

http://www.atriviss.com/home  

now in both the cases home controller is invoked and as the default controller is home and also default action is 'view' for home.

So in both cases I should get the same page.. but it doesn't

i hope this will make the question clearer